# Swift Generic Array

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, swift-protocols

This is a problem that I always come across in Swift, which i think 5.7 solves by using `any`. But, is there any other solution for trying to create a generic class array.

I wanted to create an array of all types that conform to `Base<T>`, but only the precise types are allowed.

```
import Foundation

protocol Value {
    var humanized: String? { get }
}

class AValue: Value {
    
    var humanized: String? {
        nil
    }
    
    
}

class AbstractType<T: CustomStringConvertible>: AValue {
    let value: T
    init(_ v: T) {
        self.value = v
    }
    override var humanized: String {
        value.description
    }
}

class Bol: AbstractType<Bool> { }
class Doub: AbstractType<Double> { }


class Base<T: AValue> {
    var values: [T]?
}

typealias AbstractBase = Base

var a = [AbstractBase]()

class Lab: Base<Doub>{
}
class Condition: Base<Bol> { }


let b = Bol(true)
let d = Doub(1.1)
let bb = Condition()
bb.values = [b]
let dd = Lab()
dd.values = [d]


bb.values?.first?.humanized
a.append(bb) // CANNOT ADD
a.append(dd) // Cannot convert value of type 'Base<Bol>' to expected argument type 'Base<AValue>'
for a in a {
    print(a.values?.first?.humanized)
}
```

`Bol` is a subclass of `AValue`

Comment: A generic type is not the same as `Any`. It can represent only one type at a time. In other words what you need is a protocol and make those types conform to it.

Comment: If i use a protocol with an `associatedtype`, i cannot make an array of it. (again, this was solved by 5.7 using `= [any AbstractBase]`